# (node: 15702) How to remove DeprecationWarning on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I am getting a deprecation warning message on my shell while using Node.js. It started showing up in the middle of my project, and I'm not sure how to get rid of it...

I have installed Axios, Express and Mongoose as dependencies. This is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

This is what shows on the terminal:

```
yarn run v1.17.0
$ nodemon src/index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
(node:15702) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the depecration warning?

```
(node:15702) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found a fix. Added => **useCreateIndex: true,** (worked like a charm).

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-h2xcd.mongodb.net/<project>?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
});
```